# ECONNREFUSED Error When Attempting GET on PSQL Database Using Node.js and node-postgres

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, postgresql, express

I receive the following error when using my browser to make a GET request for all entries in a database table:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
> Error in GET /products

The relevant folder structure looks like:

```
server/
  db/
    index.js
  routes/
    products.js
  index.js
```

The files involved are:

server/index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.port || 3001;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

// const usersRouter = require('./routes/users')
// app.use('/users', usersRouter)
// const authRouter = require('./routes/auth')
// app.use(['/login', '/register'], authRouter)
const productsRouter = require('./routes/products')
app.use('/products', productsRouter)
// const cartsRouter = require('./routes/carts')
// app.use('/carts', cartsRouter)
// const ordersRouter = require('./routes/orders')
// app.use('/orders', ordersRouter)

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

Initializes the server on port 3001 and creates productsRouter.

---

server/db/index.js

```
const { Pool, Client } = require("pg");

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "ecommerce",
  password: "postgres",
  port: "5432",
});

module.exports = {
  query: (text, params, callback) => {
    return pool.query(text, params, callback)
  },
}
```

Provides the function for making queries.

---

server/routes/products.js

```
const express = require("express");
const products = express.Router();
const db = require("../db/index");

products.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const products = await db.query("SELECT * FROM products");
    return res.status(201).send(products.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
    console.log("Error in GET /products");
    res.status(500).send("Server Error Occurred");
  }
});
```

Provides Node.js logic for making requests using db.query calls.

---

Steps to produce error:

1. Launch/connect Postbird on port 5432 on localhost.
2. Run ‘node index.js’ on server/index.js to start Node.js server
   listening on port 3001.
3. Navigate browser to localhost:3001/products to initiate GET request.

Comment: This is your server refusing the connection .. This can be any of the following: Firewall configurations, Anti-virus, incorrect port, Incorrect PSQL configuration, PSQL not running .. There is so much to check .. There needs to be some discovery/verification done on your part before anyone here can even look in the right direction .. IMHO

Comment: Thanks, @Zak . Firewall was off, anti-virus off, port was indeed 5432 in Postbird and in the configuration file, PSQL was running, not sure what you mean by PSQL configuration aside from that. Could you advise further with that info?

Comment: Actually, @Zak , does connecting to my database using Postbird not mean that my PSQL server is running? I'm really confused now.

Answer (score 2):

Self-taught programmer here. So it turns out that when Codecademy told me to install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), I didn't realize it was truly, essentially a mostly separate system from my main OS. I was using WSL's terminal in VS Code and when I ran 'node index.js', index.js was running on WSL. Therefore, it was unaware of the perfectly good, perfectly accessible instance of Postgresql running on port 5432 of my main OS.

Basically, it was refusing to connect to port 5432 on WSL because there wasn't any Postgres instance listening on that port of WSL; in fact, it wasn't even installed on WSL.

I switched to my Bash terminal, ran 'node index.js', navigated my browser to the URL that calls the GET request which returns the results of a SELECT on all tables in my database, and voila! It worked.